# How to send JSON data with form data using Flask

Tags: flask, flask-wtforms

I'm making a system to track entries to a sports day event and I can get the data from the form to the Python back-end but I don't know how to get the data for the event entries to the back-end too.

I have a form I've already created using Flask and WTForms and I can submit all the data relating to the user but since they can enter from just a single event all the way up to every event they are able to enter the form will have a variable number of selection fields, I want to pack this data from the selection fields into a JSON string and then have Python process it since that is very easy. My only problem is, how can I get this data into a JSON string then send it in a single request to the back-end with the other data, like first name, last name etc.

Screenshot showing the user interface of the form
[image]

Answer (score 0):

```py
from flask import jsonify

@app.route('/selects')
def selects():
   selects = ['one', 'two']
   return jsonify(selects)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have the same question and found answer in this tutorial. If you already use WTForm to make the form, the content can be access via methods. This should be straightforward. https://pythonspot.com/category/pro/web/page/2/